# Take Snapshot using webcam and EmguCV in c# in console application

Tags: c#, emgucv

I need a simple, but complete, example of capturing a snapshot from Logitech USB webcam in a console application, but I don't find.

The next instruction not works.

```
private Capture _capture = null; //Camera
```

Where is Capture definition? In the Emgu.CV.World not it is.

I use the 3.2.0 version of EmguCV.

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php?title=Camera_Capture

Thank you in advance.

[The error is the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNX1n.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the entire article? It is instantiated here:

```
 private void SetupCapture(int Camera_Identifier)
    {
        //update the selected device
        CameraDevice = Camera_Identifier;

       //Dispose of Capture if it was created before
        if (_capture != null) _capture.Dispose();
        try
        {
            //Set up capture device
            _capture = new Capture(CameraDevice);
            _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Doug

Comment: The problem is with de using of Capture class. What using is necessary?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question.

Comment: There is no Capture class in V3.2, it is called VideoCapture. Try using the VideoCapture class. I am sure you will have to make adjustments as I am not certain this class functions like the Capture class did.